# Dining philosophers from Rust documentation do not eat concurrently

Tags: concurrency, rust

I'm trying to follow the [dining philosophers example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/dining-philosophers.html) from the Rust documentation. Final code from the link:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};

struct Philosopher {
    name: String,
    left: usize,
    right: usize,
}

impl Philosopher {
    fn new(name: &str, left: usize, right: usize) -> Philosopher {
        Philosopher {
            name: name.to_string(),
            left: left,
            right: right,
        }
    }

    fn eat(&self, table: &Table) {
        let _left = table.forks[self.left].lock().unwrap();
        thread::sleep_ms(150);
        let _right = table.forks[self.right].lock().unwrap();

        println!("{} is eating.", self.name);

        thread::sleep_ms(1000);

        println!("{} is done eating.", self.name);
    }
}

struct Table {
    forks: Vec<Mutex<()>>,
}

fn main() {
    let table = Arc::new(Table { forks: vec![
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
        Mutex::new(()),
    ]});

    let philosophers = vec![
        Philosopher::new("Judith Butler", 0, 1),
        Philosopher::new("Gilles Deleuze", 1, 2),
        Philosopher::new("Karl Marx", 2, 3),
        Philosopher::new("Emma Goldman", 3, 4),
        Philosopher::new("Michel Foucault", 0, 4),
    ];

    let handles: Vec<_> = philosophers.into_iter().map(|p| {
        let table = table.clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            p.eat(&table);
        })
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
Michel Foucault is eating.
Michel Foucault is done eating.
Emma Goldman is eating.
Emma Goldman is done eating.
Karl Marx is eating.
Karl Marx is done eating.
Gilles Deleuze is eating.
Gilles Deleuze is done eating.
Judith Butler is eating.
Judith Butler is done eating.
```

According to the documentation, the philosophers should be able to eat at the same time. Desired result is something like this:

```
Gilles Deleuze is eating.
Emma Goldman is eating.
Emma Goldman is done eating.
Gilles Deleuze is done eating.
Judith Butler is eating.
Karl Marx is eating.
Judith Butler is done eating.
Michel Foucault is eating.
Karl Marx is done eating.
Michel Foucault is done eating.
```

Unfortunately, this does not happen no matter how often the code is being executed.

I'm currently using `rustc 1.5.0 (3d7cd77e4 2015-12-04)` on Windows, but the problem occurs on the Rust playground as well. Feel free to [try it yourself](http://is.gd/QOvOw0).

Comment: You are never putting back the left fork. Thus everyone takes the left fork and waits for 150 ms. Then everone has the left fork and noone can take the right fork except for "Gilles Deleuze". In fact the only reason this doesn't deadlock is that "Michale Foucault"'s left fork is also "Judith Butler"'s left fork and his right fork is also "Emma Goldmann"'s right fork.

Comment: @ker: Note that the example comes straight from the Rust book https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/dining-philosophers.html and I agree it seems bizarre... Oh, and Michel Foucault should likely have the forks (4, 0) and not (0, 4) and when I do so I hit a deadlock in the playpen :)

Comment: @ker: Ah, never mind, apparently Michel Foucault is left-handed, though I do not see how this helps exactly...

Comment: it helps in that 4/5 philosophers take the left fork first, thus there's one fork left, on the left side of Michel Foucault, thus there's a fork someone can take into their right hand. -> no deadlock

Comment: @ker: Yes, I meant I did not see how it helped answering the question (I did get it solved the problem itself). On the other hand, I played around on the playpen and the executions are always very deterministic. Even when two possible events could occur (either Judith or Michel can grab Fork 0 first), only one of them ever occurred across a (small) sample of executions and I had to take matters into my own hands (introducing targeted sleeps) to shuffle the order. Also... this solution seems inconsistent with the output presented in the book, as it leaves little room for concurrency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of the problem and the suggested output do not match because of the sleep between picking forks.

I am unsure as to why *Michel Foucault* always starts first (probably the way thread dispatch works), but the rest is easily explained.

Due to the pause (*) between grabbing the main-hand and off-hand forks, there are two phases:

- Phase 1: grab your main-hand fork
- Phase 2: grab your off-hand fork

After phase 1:

- Fork 0 is in the hand of either Michel Foucault or Judith Butler
- Fork 1 is in the hand of Gilles Deleuze
- Fork 2 is in the hand of Karl Marx
- Fork 3 is in the hand of Emma Goldman

Now, note that only Fork 4 is available for grab!

We have two cases in Phase 2:

a) Judith grabbed the Fork 0
 b) Michel grabbed the Fork 0

Starting with (a):

- All philosophers are blocked except Emma, who grabs Fork 4
- When Emma is done, she releases Fork 3, which Karl immediately grabs
- When Karl is done...
- Finally, Judith is done, she releases Fork 0, and Michel eats

In case (a), only one philosopher can eat at any given time.

*Note: I forced the case by pausing Michel for 150ms before letting him grab his first fork.*

The case (b) is more complicated as once again we have a race, this time between Emma and Michel to grab Fork 4. We are gentlemen, so Emma will go first and the case of Michel grabbing Fork 4 is now named (c):

- Emma grabs Fork 4, all other philosophers are now blocked
- When Emma is done, she releases Fork 3 and 4, both Michel and Karl jump on them
- When Michel is done, he releases Forks 0 and 4, Judith immediately grabs it... and starts waiting; nobody cares about Fork 4 now
- When Karl is done, he releases Fork 2, which Gilles immediately grabs
- When Gilles is done, he releases Fork 1, which Judith immediately grabs
- When Judith is done, all 5 have eaten

We observe very limited concurrency here: Emma hits first, and only when she is finished do we have two parallel streams, one with Michel, and one going Karl > Gilles > Judith.

*Note: I forced the case by pausing Michel for 150ms before letting him grab his second fork.*

Finally, we have case (c):

- Michel grabs Fork 4, all other philosophers are now blocked
- When Michel is done, he releases Fork 4 and 0, which are grabbed respectively by Emma and Judith; Judith is still blocked (first sleeping, then waiting for Fork 1) but Emma starts eating
- When Emma is done...

And here again, no concurrency at all.

(*) This is not actually guaranteed, but 150ms being a long time computer-wise, unless the machine is very loaded, it will just happen.

---

While the solution proposed by the book does work (there is no deadlock whatever the circumstances), it does not exhibit much concurrency, so it is more an exhibit of Rust than an exhibit of concurrency... but then, it is the Rust book and not the concurrency one!

I do not understand why Michel's thread is systematically scheduled first on the playpen; but it can easily be countered by making him sleep specifically.

Answer (score 4):

This is a semi-common question for this example. Programmers tend to think of threads as "random" because threads *usually* have differing start times and run lengths. Most usages of threads also don't lock a shared resource for the entire life of the thread. Remember that threads are sort-of deterministic, because they are scheduled by an algorithm.

In this example, the main thread creates a whole bunch of threads and adds them to a queue managed by the operating system. Eventually, the main thread is blocked or is interrupted by the scheduler. The scheduler looks through the queue of threads and asks the "first" one if it can run. If it is runnable, then it is run for a time slice or until it is blocked.

The "first" thread is up to the OS. Linux, for example, has multiple tweakable schedulers that allow you to prioritize which threads run. The scheduler can also choose to interrupt a thread earlier or later

If you add a print at the very beginning of the thread, you can see that the threads do start in a different order. Here's a table of which thread starts first, based on 100 runs:

```
| Position | Emma Goldman | Gilles Deleuze | Judith Butler | Karl Marx | Michel Foucault |
|----------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------|
|        1 |            4 |              9 |            81 |         5 |               1 |
|        2 |            5 |             66 |             9 |        17 |               3 |
|        3 |           19 |             14 |             5 |        49 |              13 |
|        4 |           46 |              9 |             3 |        20 |              22 |
|        5 |           26 |              2 |             2 |         9 |              61 |
```

If I'm doing my statistics correctly, the most common starting order is:

1. Judith Butler
2. Gilles Deleuze
3. Karl Marx
4. Emma Goldman
5. Michel Foucault

Note that this matches the sequence of philosophers defined in the code!

Also note that the algorithm itself imposes an ordering. All but one philosopher picks up the fork on the left hand first, then waits a bit. If the threads run in order, then each one in turn is waiting on the one before it. Most of the threads have a dependence on the thread sitting to the "left". If we pictured a circular table with everyone holding a left fork (a deadlock), and we picked one person to give an extra fork to (breaking the deadlock), then you can see there would be a cascade of people able to eat.

Also remember that `println!` uses standard out; a mutable global resource that must be protected by a mutex. As such, printing can cause the thread to be blocked and rescheduled.

I am on OS X, which likely explains the order that I semi-consistently get that is different from yours.

Comment: In the playpen, Michel Foucault always starts before Judith Butler; I wonder what degree of parallelism the playpen offers...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The playpen caches a program's output for a certain time. If you run the exact same program multiple times, you'll get the output from the cache.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: I know, I cheated by tweaking the program (adding spaces/comments) between runs after I realized it. The time difference between the return of a cached display and a real display was rather obvious.